# how do if scroll event down can add class and if up can remove class (NO JQuery)

Tags: javascript

i want add and remove class with event scroll but im always find jquery

can use pure JS without Jquery Library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const elementYouWantAddClass = document.getElementById('mvArea');
window.addEventListener('scroll', ()=>{ 
    if ( window.scrollY > 0) {
        elementYouWantAddClass.classList.add("resize");
    } else {
        elementYouWantAddClass.classList.remove("resize");
    }
});
```

okay im find that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY

with scrollY can be number value